# Is there an easy way to read a PetscBag into a python dict?

Tags: petsc, python

I'm using a PetscBag to store the input parameters of my program. At some point, I'm going to need to use python to plot these parameters against some output parameters, and `dict`s along with matplotlib seem to be the way to go with this.

Basically, I want to use `PetscBagView()` or something like it to write a petsc bag to a file, and then use some python thing (built-in part of the standard library, external package especially for this purpose, whatever works) to read it into a `dict`. The idea is to make it easy to write matplotlib code that plots various input parameters against certain output parameters.

If `dict`s are the wrong thing to use for plotting the inputs of several simulations against their outputs, what should I use?

**Is there an easy way to read a (binary or ascii) serialized PetscBag into python as a `dict` ?**

Comment: Are you using petsc4py?

Comment: No, I'm just using the C bindings. Does using petsc4py require you to do everything in python, or is it just a python interface in addition to the c/c++/fortran interfaces?

Comment: I think it's a Python API. I don't think it requires you to do everything in Python, although I believe you could use that package to do everything in Python if you wanted to. You'd have to check the web site. AronAhmadia knows more about it than I do.

Comment: There's no Bag object in petsc4py, and it sounds like a rather complicated object to write an interface for.  How complicated are your input parameters?

Comment: Lisandro points at the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module the in the Python standard library.  You can [check the source code for PetscBagView](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/sys/bag/bag.c.html#PetscBagView) to get an idea of how to unpack it.  I think Matt implemented this functionality so he might have a more complete answer.

Comment: Dan, I'm guessing you need a little more help on the question since you've put a bounty on it.  The short answer is obviously no, but can you give us an example of the way you're building the PetscBag object?

Comment: @Dan - do you mind providing a few more details in your question?

Comment: Sorry Dan, let me be more clear.  The type of Python object is not as important as the process for constructing it.  The way to unbag/deserialize your data file and construct the dict is going to depend on what sort of things you are putting in the serialized Bag file.  If it is very nasty/complicated, somebody would have to implement a full deserializer to make things work for you.  It would be good to know specifically what objects you are putting (or planning to put) in the bag.

Comment: The bag would have `int`s, `PetscScalar`s and strings. I'd really only need to read in the `int`s and scalars to make plots, though.